# Status of adding data extension with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am using Add() function to add a new data extension and I would like to access a status message if possible. I am using following code

```
var deObj = {
        "CustomerKey" : "demoDE",
        "Name" : "My Demo DE",
        "Fields" : [
          { "Name" : "Field 1", "FieldType" : "Number" },
          { "Name" : "Field 2", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
          { "Name" : "Field 3", "FieldType" : "Date", "Ordinal" : 2 },
        ]
    };

var myDE = DataExtension.Add(deObj);
```

Data extension is created succesfully.

Variable myDE returns following, I don't know what it means

```
{ 
   "Fields":{ 
      "Add":"function",
      "Remove":"function",
      "Retrieve":"function",
      "Update":"function",
      "UpdateSendableField":"function"
   },
   "Remove":"function",
   "Update":"function",
   "Rows":{ 
      "Lookup":"function",
      "Add":"function",
      "Remove":"function",
      "Update":"function",
      "Retrieve":"function"
   }
}
```

Can you please advise what it means when it writes function everywhere?

Is there a way to return status, something like Success or Error?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So basically what you are seeing is the 'success' message. If it did not work, it would actually force an error on the page (Jint.Native.JsException throws "Error adding data extension").

What I would recommend is using a Try/Catch around it and you can set a value inside of it to show success or fail for your records.

E.g.

```
try{
  var myDE = DataExtension.Add(deObj);
  var status = 'Success';
  return status;
} catch(e) {
  var status = 'Fail';
  return status;
}
```

This should help you handle errors better and provide the status of the call as well.